# Windows 10 is it possible to put photos/images in fullscreen with the photo app?

Tags: windows-10, photos, fullscreen

This question was already asked at the [Corporate's](https://answers.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/comment-mettre-photos-en-plein-%C3%A9cran-ou/e853a404-421e-4b7d-a819-9318a5a0b46d) forum (Comment mettre Photos en plein écran ? ou contrôler le diaporama), but lacked in my opinion a satisfying answer and it's locked now.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way of getting a somewhat usable fullscreen mode with the Windows 10 Photo viewing app:

1. Open a photo with the app from within a directory full of photos (you would have guessed that one already).
2. Enter diaporama mode (from top right menu, probably hidden in the dots ... à la more menu).
3. Immediately hit the SPACE bar.

**Now the diaporama is in paused mode.**

You can use arrow keys ← and → to navigate backwards, forwards resp. or SPACE to resume the diaporama. But remember that any of the aforementioned action will resume the diaporama. Therefore, you must hit the SPACE bar again.

As a result, to navigate, cycle through the following steps:

4. Hit ←, → or SPACE (diaporama thus resumes).
5. Hit SPACE (to pause the diaporama again).

Voilà. Well voilà indeed, but don't you think it's kinda cumbersome for something like that which should really be straightforward in any image/photo viewing app?

Regards.

---

Note: moved here from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65960648/windows-10-is-it-possible-to-put-photos-images-in-fullscreen-with-the-photo-app/65960649#65960649

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: It seems that the diaporama won't zoom out fullscreen the photos that are smaller than the resolution of the screen. So it's a shame. It's not working that well after all. Really, seriously, no simple image viewing app out there?

Comment: Any real way to achieve that is welcome. I'll be happy to up-vote your solution. Thanks.